# How could i add an on click event to this checkbox? (HTML Helpers)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor, checkbox

I have a checkbox as follows:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ItemsEdit", "Items", FormMethod.Post))
       {

            @Html.CheckBox("itemCheck")

       }
```

I want to be able to send an additional value to a controller when it is clicked, similar to something like this:

```
<input id = "@dataLineItem.Split(Model.ItemList.delimiterChar)[0]" type="checkbox" value="true" name="Remember" onclick="sendCheckId(this.id)" />
```

Below is the jQuery i am using to pass this id value to my controller:

```
function sendCheckId(checkedId) {
        var sentId = checkedId;
        $.post("/Items/ItemsEdit/", { sendIdToAction: sentId })
    }
```

However, if i were to use the method above, i wouldnt know how to pass the 'true/false' values of the checkbox, to the same controller.

Comment: Do you want to call a controller action or a javascript function. both need different approaches.

Comment: I have updated my question with the JS i am using to send the id value to my controller when the checkbox is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try `onclick="sendCheckId(this.id,this.value)"`

I'm not sure what that sendCheckId function leads to, but it should be pretty quick and easy to expand it to include the second value.

Comment: Unfortunately i don't believe its possible to pass the value attribute in the same manner as the id. So i think by doing this, 'this.value' will not result to anything.

Comment: I do it daily in my own code. For some reason I can't do functions in my codepen, but alert works. https://codepen.io/rldeckard/pen/gOaxNoP?editors=1111

Comment: Oh this does in fact work, apologies. I feel i was skeptical for IntelliSense not suggesting 'value'. Appreciate it a ton! cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that i could simply do this using the Razor engine:

```
@Html.CheckBox("itemCheck", new
{
     onclick = "alert('Hello')"
}
```

Credit: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/how-to-call-on-click-event-in-mvc-5

(The answer by Ramesh Palanivel)